# Dump variable to file

Tags: python

I am brand new at python and coming from php.  How do I dump all contents of a variable into a file, similarly to var_dump?  After searching around, i've come up with this:

```
from inspect import getmembers
from pprint import pprint
pprint(getmembers(_variable_))
```

However it shows up in the command window not a friendly readable file.  I do know how to write to a file and i've tried this:

```
f.write(pprint(getmembers(_variable_)))
```

But it gives me a type error.  Would appreciate help, thanks.

Comment: take a look at pickle module

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)? It's in the standard library, and it should pretty much work like this :

```
import pickle

# Write to file
pickle.dump(obj, open("file.dat", "wb"))

# Read that file
obj = pickle.load(open("file.dat", "rb"))
```

Comment: I believe this is what im looking for but im not sure how to read it.  What im looking for is to be able to read through the dump and see all of the structures in a readable way. With pickle, some of the data is human readable but not all of it.

Comment: Try "json" instead of pickle - as in `import json; json.dump(obj, ...) - it is "human readable" - but it can only encode native types such as numbers, strings dictionaries and lists - while pickle works for arbitrary Python objects

Comment: JSON might be what you want then. It's less complete than `pickle`, but it does the trick if everything you use are "simple" objects, like @jsbueno says.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're happy with how the output of `pprint` looks and you're not looking for object serialization, [`pformat`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pformat) does what you you're trying to do.

```
from pprint import pformat
f.write(pformat(getmembers(_variable_)))
```

Comment: I think what im looking for is serialization such as pickle.

Comment: Are you planning on reading the object back into memory? If yes, then serialization is definitely what you need. If this is just something for a human to be able to read, then you probably don't. Your program, so only you can tell. Good luck.